# Can't log into my iCloud account from Windows 8

Tags: icloud

I have got Windows 8 and I have tried several times to log into iCloud account, but nothing is working. The only way I am able to access my photos is if I go online to the iCloud website and log on. There has got to be something that I am doing wrong.

Comment: Do you get an error message? Where exactly are you trying to log in?

Answer (score 1):

Is this the first time you've tried to access your account through iCloud's App on windows? I also had a similar issue with Windows 8.1 a week ago. 
The way I managed to solve this problem was uninstalling the iCloud from my computer, restarting, and reinstalling back the application.

Here is the [Apple Support Guide for Setting up iCloud on Windows](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201391).